# How to reload an image in Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am working on a flask app in which I generate a polar plot. 
The function creating the plot saves a file (jpg) with the figure like this:

```
def polar_figure(df, player_):
    ....
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (20,20), )
    ....
    # Save the plot
    plt.savefig('static/'+str(player_)+'_plot.png', transparent = True, bbox_inches = 'tight')
    return 'static/'+str(player_)+'_plot.png'
```

and the app generates an url:

```
player_pic_url = '/static/'+str(player)+'_pic.jpg'

return render_template(player_pic_url = player_pic_url)
```

that is then loaded by the index.html

```
<img src={{player_pic_url}} alt="picture" style="width:100%; border-radius: 65%; border: 20px solid transparent;">
```

The problem is that every time I reload the app in the browser, it keeps showing the same graph, even though the file, as expected, changes with the new data.

**So, the question is if there is a way to ask the app to load the file every time it is reloaded?**

Thanks.

Comment: Is the image perhaps being cached, so your browser isn’t reloading it each time?

Comment: That is possible. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: I’m not sure. You could try doing a force-refresh in the browser to verify that is the issue. (Cmd-shift-R on Mac, Ctrl-shift-r on Windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the cache of your navigator.
you shouldn't have the same name for two different image
So just generate a different name for each image you upload:

```
image_name = "{}_{}.png".format(player_name,datetime.datetime.utc_now().isoformat())  # could be a uuid instead of datetime
plt.savefig('static/{}'.format(image_name), transparent = True, bbox_inches = 'tight')
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution. How should I deal with the multiple files created with every option change?

Comment: Youpi should savez the URL and other attributes in a database. An other would be to increment version number as a suffice of URL for each new image but you still have to now the version number by saving it somewhere. <img src={{player_pic_url}}?v={version_number} You can keep the same name like this and the nav will ask for the file if he does.not have this URL in cache

Comment: I added: [os.remove(file) for file in glob.glob('static/*_polar_plot.png')] to my function to delete the extra files.